# Generator for random long hex strings in PHP

Tags: php, generator

I have written a generator of strings, but I don't know how to create a *random hex* string with length, for instance 100 digits, for inserting into a database. All these strings have to be same length.

How can I generate random hex strings?

Comment: And how does your current generator work? For example, if it currently takes a random character from the string "ABC..XYZ", why don't you change that to "0123456789ABCDEF"? You should be able to modify it easily.

Comment: Why can't you use a loop with 100 cyles per string you need and use random() to generate a random number between 0 and 15 and convert that to a propper hex character?

Comment: @arkascha it sounds very good, can you put there piece of your code, i am beginer in php, i will be thankful for everything. How would you realise that please?

Comment: Well take a look at the answer @WebnetMobile.com gave below. He coded exactly what I suggested.

Comment: `<?php
$val = '';
for( $i=0; $i<100; $i++ ) {
   $val .= chr( rand( 65, 90 ) );
echo"<br>".sha1(($val));
}

?>`  
yes it works!:) and output is for example: 72c8e80ba38c19ca2724c2ca33ffa651fa3fdafc

how can i get bigger string please?:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this answers OP's question, if what you are looking for is **random**, then @danorton answer may be a better fit.

---

Like this:

```
$val = '';
for( $i=0; $i<100; $i++ ) {
   $val .= chr(rand(65, 90));
}
```

65 is `A` while 90 is `Z`. if you do not like "magic numbers" this form may be more readable:

```php
$val = '';
for( $i=0; $i<100; $i++ ) {
   $val .= chr(rand(ord('A'), ord('Z')));
}
```

I'd make `ord()` result a variable and move it out of the loop though for performance reasons:

```php
$A = ord('A');
$Z = ord('Z');
$val = '';
for( $i=0; $i<100; $i++ ) {
   $val .= chr(rand($A, $Z));
}
```

Or you could glue output of `sha1()`s (three of them) and cut down to 100 chars. Or use `md5()` instead (but I'd stick to `sha1()`).

**EDIT** `sha1()` outputs 40 chars long string, `md5()` 32 chars long. So if you do not want to glue char by char (as in loop I gave above) try this function

```
function getId($val_length) {
    $result = '';
    $module_length = 40;   // we use sha1, so module is 40 chars
    $steps = round(($val_length/$module_length) + 0.5);

    for( $i=0; $i<$steps; $i++ ) {
      $result .= sha1(uniqid() . md5(rand());
    }

    return substr($result, 0, $val_length);
}
```

where function argument is length of string to be returned. Call it `getId(100);`

Comment: <?php $val = ''; for( $i=0; $i<100; $i++ ) { $val .= chr( rand( 65, 90 ) ); echo"<br>".sha1(($val)); } ?> yes it works!:) and output is for example: 72c8e80ba38c19ca2724c2ca33ffa651fa3fdafc how can i get bigger string please?:)

Comment: Adding two uniqid()'s has no impact. One is sufficient. 

Interestingly, having none increases collisions by a factor of 3. 

On a sample size of 10 million, there are on average around 11,000 collisions with your code (with two or one uniqid()'s - doesn't make a difference). Remove uniqid() and the collisions increase to 35,000. Either way, it's the difference between a 99.89% chance of no collisions and a 99.65% chance.

Answer (score 44):

As of PHP 5.3 with OpenSSL extension:

```
function getRandomHex($num_bytes=4) {
  return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($num_bytes));
}
```

For your example of 100 digits:

```
$str = getRandomHex(50);
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: I agree that this is the most secure way, but depending on the use case (when security is not a concern) I would prefere a solution that does not requre an additional PHP extensions (`ext-openssl` in this case)

Answer (score 5):

```
$randHexStr = implode( array_map( function() { return dechex( mt_rand( 0, 15 ) ); }, array_fill( 0, $strlen, null ) ) );
```

where $strlen is length of random hex string.

Answer (score 4):

From php7 on you should use the function [random_bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php):

```
function getRandomHex($num_bytes=4) {
  return bin2hex(random_bytes($num_bytes));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

liner technique to do so, but its bit complicated and hard-coded in-terms of length of string.

$rand4 = substr(sha1(rand(0,getrandmax())),rand(0,24),16);

in which you need to change the last varibale of function (which i set to 16) if you want to change the length of output string and one more thing there is one rand(0,24) in which number 24 will change according to third variable, it should not be more then 40-thirdvariable...

Answer (score 0):

I like to a have single general function that can handle similar situations. By that I mean a function which receives both the requried length of the generated string and the possible characters that can occure in it.

That way a single function can create: 40-digit decimal number, 16-digit uppercase hex number, 100 letter lowercase string, etc...

Here is my implementation:

```
/**
 * Generate a random string.
 *
 * @param int    $length Length of the generated string.
 * @param string $chars  The string containing all of the available characters.
 *
 * @return string The generated string.
 */
function getRandomString($length = 10, $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789') {
    $str = '';

    $size = strlen($chars);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $str .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $size - 1)];
    }

    return $str;
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** Do not use this function to generate random string for any security purpose. For a secure string generator check out the answer from @danorton.